# Angular 4: Best practices to catch custom error from model

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have an Angular4 application which the model does all the validation stuff while inputing the data (if the input is wrong the model throws an error and do not set the variable), so the ideal case would be to link any input change directly to the set method related to the model, these would make the components very lean and scaleable.
My first strategy was to make a directive which I pass the setter method and my directive does the try/catch handle

My html would be:

```
<div class="input-field col s12" appFormSetter [setFunction]="session?.getPlayer()?.setName">
   <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
   <input #input placeholder="João da Silva" type="text" class="validate" 
          [ngModel]='session.getPlayer()?.getName()' name="name">
   <label for="first_name" class="active">Nome</label>
</div>
```

The directive would be:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
   selector: '[appFormSetter]'
})
export class FormSetterDirective {

  @Input() setFunction;

  @HostListener('input') onInput() {
    try {
        this.setFunction(this.elRef.nativeElement.value);
    } catch (error) {
        // Would catch the error and show in some <small>
        console.log('Error', error);
    }
  }

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
    console.log('mychildren', this.inputElement);
  }
}
```

And the model would be:

```
public setName(name: string): void {
    if(!isValid()) throw 'myError';
    this.name = name;
}
```

What is the best practices to handle something like this?
Can I get the error directly through the html without going through the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ReactiveFormsModule](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). It has change detection and validation handling.
I gave an answer that involved cookies an a template for Required validation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191501/495157).
Download the example, have a play around with the live example.

If you hover over links you'll see one has 'final' in link. The other you'd have to go thru and add code manually. I'd suggest using 'final' version.

Also if you go to [Angular.io](https://angular.io/) and search on "validator" you'll be able to find examples of things like EmailValidator, PatternValidator. Here's the main [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) class.

If you want to learn more Angular University has an excellent course on it.
They've got a YouTube channel and their code is on Github.
You need to work out which branches to check out from following along with videos:
"[Rxjs and Reactive Patterns Angular Architecture Course](https://angular-university.io/course/reactive-angular-architecture-course)".

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer =) I've seen the reactive forms module, but they do not seen scaleable at all. Imagine I have a create and update page for my model, this approach I would have to manually include the validators in both component, actually I would have to replicate almost all my code. I want to use the fact that my model has a validation method that I can use anywhere in the code, get it?

Comment: It sounds like an abstract base class with most of functionality built in that the two components would derive from would be one way to go. I'd have thought one component with an *ngIF would have sufficed though based on a mode...

Comment: I think I get what you mean about not having the validator rules defined in one place at a domain model level though, having used GORM with Grails. Putting it in the component seems to go against the define/maintain in one place rule...