# How can I make my Application more Scalable and Flexible using Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have something like this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/GYWY2HxFz41tmiXswFNs/), my original code has some changes Like Keyboard events and Mouse Events.

The code is working as a single Component, my problem is that I have to create a lot of Card-List with different data but I need to create at the same time another Cards-Something that contains the same MouseEvents and Keyboard Events than the "Card-List" but with different data and styles.

In my case it will be something like "`User-Card-List`" that will be different of "`Notifications-Cards`" and "`Person-Card-List`" but all the Cards will have something like a **Global** `Card-Container-Component` that contains a `Service` to get the Mouse and Keyboard Events.

I created MouseService and KeyboardService

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592972/is-it-possible-to-use-hostlistener-in-a-service) `@HostListener` seems like it's not possible to use it in a service.

So I used this to get for example the Ctrl Keyboard Events.

```
@Injectable()
export class KeyboardService {

  public isCtrlKeyDown = false;

  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 17 && !this.isCtrlKeyDown) {
        this.isCtrlKeyDown = true;
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 17 && this.isCtrlKeyDown) {
        this.isCtrlKeyDown = false;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

and Now I need to know how Can I make something like the Plunker for a more Scalable and Flexible App and I'm not sure if [Angular Projection](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/projection.html) is exactly what I need because I will have in the same Web View 2 or 3 different card components (Notification-Cards will be in all views with another card-component).

I hope you can understand me =) Thanks.

Comment: If it's something like always wanting a list with different components inside, sound like you need to look at content projection.

Comment: Thanks, I will read about content projection.

Comment: Joshua Morony talked about content projection in this video. It's an Ionic video but the content projection part and things like @ContentChildren equally apply to Angular 2/4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYvIjd8rCVQ Hope it gives you some ideas. - involves <ngContent>

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't tie in much to HostListener.

- I don't think the code below, on its own totally answers your question, but if you separate the concerns of your Angular classes into 'smart' vs 'presentational' components, it might also help you organise your code base. It seems to fit your overall needs.
- There's some footnotes at the end to address the other parts of your needs.

Here's the gist of it:

smart.component.ts

```
// Smart because it's aware of service layer //
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Domain} from '../shared/model/domain';
import {DomainService} from '../services/domain-service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
    selector:    'smart-component',
    templateUrl:'./smart-component.html',
    stylesUrl: ['./smart-component.css']
})
export class SmartComponent implements OnInit {
   domains$ : Observable<Domain[]>; // define data stream view needs.
   constructor(private domainService : DomainService) {}

   ngOnInit {
     this.domains$ = this.domainService.findAllDomains();
   }
}
```

smart.component.html

```
<presentation-list [domains]="domains$ | async"></presentation-list>
```

presentation-component.ts

```
// handles layout only //
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Domain} from '../shared/model/domain';
@Component({
    selector:    'presentation-list',
    templateUrl:'./presentation-component.html',
    stylesUrl: ['./presentation-component.css']  
})
export class PresentationComponent {
  @Input()
  domains: Domain[];
  // see smart.component.html calling presentation-list [domains]
  // presentation-list is the selector of this class.
}
```

presentation-component.html

```
<table *ngIf="domains else loadingDomain">
  <tr *ngFor="let domain of domains">
    <td>
        {{domain.field}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<template #loadingDomain>
  <div>Loading data ...</div>
</template>
```

---

Another thing to do would be:

1. Define a common interface for the methods, the services of your different domain classes will need.
2. Write services that implement the common interface for your domain classes.

For 'data changes' I would have been thinking:

- [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). I gave some hints on other aspects of setting up a project to use them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188006/how-to-restrict-browser-refresh-based-on-whether-rendered-form-component-on-a-pa/45191501#45191501)
- [ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html).

The comments about content projection and `<ngContent></ngContent>` I made could still apply. Maybe there's a way to define  Directive(s) that swaps out the different implementations. If someone adds to this with their two cents on this it would be useful to me too.

Comment: You were Right, I changed the question and the first Question was an stupid question because now I can get Mouse and Keyboard events from Service but im not sure if that is the correct way to make an app more flexible and scalable.

Comment: I've tried running your Plunker example now you've added it. Since I am not seeing at least two implementations of cards giving a different visual cues have left me dumbfounded as to how to help you, because I feel I don't have a grasp of your needs. i.e. I don't now what I'm supposed to be doing/seeing when I run the app other than clicking some cards...